# Oracle: Nested blocks inside a if then else

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was just wondering I'm not really an expert in PL/SQL so this might have been answered but can we have a nested pl/sql block inside a if then else statement. For example:

```
DECLARE
 cnt number;
<<PARENT BLOCK>>
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO n_cnt_iti 
    FROM A JOIN B ON ...
    .....
    ....
    IF n_cnt_iti = 0 THEN
        flag = 0 
    ELSE
    <<CHILD BLOCK>>
        DECLARE
            ...
            BEGIN
                ...
```

I've made it into this because the 1st query if for initial verification and if it fails I have to declare again variables only inside for the pl/sql block

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/block.htm#LNPLS01303 "*Blocks can be nested*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Each statement block (between begin..end) can have a declare clause which declares variables and even cursors and local functions, which are only in scope in that block.

But there is also no harm in declaring the variables at the top of your stored proc. Declaring them won't cost much performance or memory, so it's a matter of personal preference how you do it.